# Conditional Probability Deck of Cards problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm working on this question which has got me stumped. Struggling to workout the probabilities for each part of the conditional equation. Here's the question (from Applied Finite Mathematics if anyone's interested)

"Three cards are randomly drawn without replacement from a standard deck of 52 cards.

What is the probability of drawing an ace on the third draw given that at least one ace was drawn on the first two draws"

The answer is given as 49/825 or 0.059

How this is arrived at? In particular how to derive the probabilities for each part of the equation. Thank you.

Comment: There's a 'given that' formula: Have you tried using that ? Link to the formula : http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/condprob.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be the number of aces drawn in the first two draws. Now let us define the following events:
$$A = \{ \text{you draw an ace in the third draw}\}$$
$$B = \{X = 1\}$$
$$C = \{X = 2\}$$

You want to know $\mathbb{P}(A | \, X \geq 1)$ which can be written as $$\mathbb{P}(A | \, B \cup C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap (B \cup C))}{\mathbb{P}(B \cup C)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) + \mathbb{P}(A \cap C)}{\mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}( C)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A | \, B)\mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(A |\, C)\mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}( C)}$$

Now it suffices to calculate each element:
$$\mathbb{P}(A |\, B)=\frac{3}{50}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(A |\, C)=\frac{2}{50}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}=\frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 48}{52 \cdot 51}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(C) = \frac{\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{2}}=\frac{4 \cdot 3}{52 \cdot 51}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I'm starting to understand it. Can you elaborate how you worked out the probability of B?

Comment: @Oaty, it's a hypergeomtric distribution. The intuiton behind it is the following: you count all combinations giving exactly one ace (chiose 1 card among 4) and one non-ace (choose 1 card among the remaining 48) over all possibile combinations (2 cards among the whole deck of 52).